# How can i disable multi subscription on pubsub node in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-hooks

I have to disable the multi subscription, I.e ability to subscribe more than once to a pubsub node

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment, but it will be the default behaviour starting from ejabberd 16.01.